# Conditional Cumulative sum based on the status of an object

Tags: r, data.table, iteration, cumsum

I'm looking for a conditional cumulative sum based on the status of an object. I'd like to sum all the previous rows when the stats is "New", but reset the cumulative sum when the status becomes "Old". I also want to iterate this over group IDs.

Thus, in the example below:

```
set.seed(5)
df <- data.table(ID=c(rep("A",10),rep("B",10)),time=c(seq(1,10),seq(1,10)),
                 Status=sample(c("New","Old"),20,replace = TRUE))
df
    ID time Status
 1:  A    1    Old
 2:  A    2    New
 3:  A    3    New
 4:  A    4    New
 5:  A    5    New
 6:  A    6    New
 7:  A    7    New
 8:  A    8    New
 9:  A    9    Old
10:  A   10    New
11:  B    1    New
12:  B    2    New
13:  B    3    New
14:  B    4    Old
15:  B    5    Old
16:  B    6    New
17:  B    7    New
18:  B    8    Old
19:  B    9    Old
20:  B   10    Old
```

The desired outcome is:

```
    ID time Status Cond_Sum
 1:  A    1    Old        0
 2:  A    2    New        1
 3:  A    3    New        2
 4:  A    4    New        3
 5:  A    5    New        4
 6:  A    6    New        5
 7:  A    7    New        6
 8:  A    8    New        7
 9:  A    9    Old        0
10:  A   10    New        1
11:  B    1    New        1
12:  B    2    New        2
13:  B    3    New        3
14:  B    4    Old        0
15:  B    5    Old        0
16:  B    6    New        1
17:  B    7    New        2
18:  B    8    Old        0
19:  B    9    Old        0
20:  B   10    Old        0
```

A data.table solution is preferable.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can  create a grouping column with `rleid` on the 'ID', 'Status', then specify the condition expression in `i` (`Status == "New"`), assign the sequence of rows (`seq_len(.N)`) to 'Cond_Sum' grouped by 'grp' (or use `rowid(grp)`)

```
library(data.table)
df[, grp := rleid(ID, Status)]
df[, Cond_Sum := 0][Status == 'New', 
          Cond_Sum := seq_len(.N), grp][, grp := NULL][]
```

-output

```
#     ID time Status Cond_Sum
# 1:  A    1    Old        0
# 2:  A    2    New        1
# 3:  A    3    New        2
# 4:  A    4    New        3
# 5:  A    5    New        4
# 6:  A    6    New        5
# 7:  A    7    New        6
# 8:  A    8    New        7
# 9:  A    9    Old        0
#10:  A   10    New        1
#11:  B    1    New        1
#12:  B    2    New        2
#13:  B    3    New        3
#14:  B    4    Old        0
#15:  B    5    Old        0
#16:  B    6    New        1
#17:  B    7    New        2
#18:  B    8    Old        0
#19:  B    9    Old        0
#20:  B   10    Old        0
```